# How do I make a function that generates a new button/label/widget when a button is pressed?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm writing a decision tree in python with kivy. The decision tree starts with one button, and I want a function that generates a new branch with a new button when the first button is pressed. For the position I am thinking a variable for the coardinates (in FloatLayout) and a + X(for excampel 0.05) for each time a new button is generated. The question is: How do I make a function that generates a new button/label/widget when a button is pressed?

I know i can make something like this:

```
visible: False
opacity: 1 if self.visible else 0
disabled: not self.visible
on_release: button2.visible = True
```

But the problem is that I then have to make a huge decision tree whit so many possibilities.

Comment: have you looked into the `.add_widget()` function?

Comment: Yes, I am trying. But I dont know where to put the ".add_widget()"-function. Should I make it in the .kv file or in the .py file? (I am new to this:/ ) Do you have an excample?